# Non-periodic perturbation in solid state

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, perturbation-theory

I want to obtain the eigenstates of a crystalline solid with a local perturbation. In other words, I want to solve the following Schrodinger Equation:
$$ H(x)=\frac{\nabla^2}{2m}+V(x)+\lambda H'(x)$$
where $V(x)$ is a periodic potential, but $H'(x)$ is not, but instead a local, small perturbation. Let's say we know the eigenstates of $H_0 \equiv \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}+V(x)$, given by the set $\{|n\rangle\}$ and we want to find the eigenstates of the complete Hamiltinain $H(x)$.

I wanted to approach this problem using standard perturbation theory. However, when we look at first-order corrections in the states, we have the following:

$$|n\rangle^{(1)}= \sum_{m\neq n} |m\rangle \frac{\langle m| H' |n\rangle}{E_n-E_m}$$

where $|n\rangle^{(1)}$ refers to the first-order correction of the states. However, in a solid, we have energy bands, which means we have a continuous spectrum. Therefore, the energy differences $E_n-E_m << \langle m| H' |n\rangle$ and it seems like perturbation theory is not the way to go in this scenario.

What are some approaches to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you need to solve it exactly? In effective mass or similar approximation it becomes a problem of a free particle in a potential.

Comment: I want to obtain an approximate solution. What do you mean by a free particle in a potential?

Comment: Like in basic QM. It is hard to say anything, since it is not clear what your potential is like.